# Understand Gulp pipe order

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-preprocess

## Context

I want to parse some `.sass` files and replace a variable before compile them into `.css`.

For this I used [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp), [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) and [gulp-preprocess](https://github.com/jas/gulp-preprocess):

```
npm install gulp gulp-sass gulp-preprocess --save-dev
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var preprocess = require('gulp-preprocess');

var settings = {
  HOST_URL: 'qa.host.com'
}

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass({indentedSyntax: true}))
    .pipe(preprocess({context: settings}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

**sass/styles.sass**

```
@import "partials/variables"

body
  background-image: url("//#{ $host_url }/foo.jpg")

.bar
  color: $red
  background-image: $host_url
```

**sass/partials/_variables.sass**

```
$red: #ff0000
$host_url: '/* @echo HOST_URL */'
```

**CLI**

```
gulp sass
```

**This works.** It creates a `dist/styles.css` file with the replaced variables as intended.

## Question:

At the first attempt I was trying to execute the `preprocess` before `sass`:

```
.pipe(preprocess({context: settings}))
.pipe(sass({indentedSyntax: true}))
```

Simply won't replace the variables:

```
body {
  background-image: url("///* @echo HOST_URL *//foo.jpg"); }

.bar {
  color: #ff0000;
  background-image: '/* @echo HOST_URL */'; }
```

So, why does the `preprocess` has to be executed after the `sass`? Won't the pipe after the sass transformation return the already compiled css? That would mean that the variables would be already applied and squashed into the stream...

Looks like that at some point the stream goes in the other direction.

Comment: It is very strange indeed. I looked at the code of [preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess), and found the [regex](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess/blob/master/lib/regexrules.js#L30) they used for matching the echo statement. Also, I can see they match .sass files and css files both with the same rules. After some fiddling around with the regex they use, I got it to match both of your cases (it was not valid, according to their rules, I'm not sure if it is different standard).
Though if it works one way, just use that. There should be no problems doing this either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work when preprocessing first:

The issue relates how the sass files are referenced when compiled. Since `style.sass` imports `partials/variables` this file is referenced outside the stream and it will retrieve the original (not preprocessed) file.

### Why it works preprocessing after:

Since the compiled `.css` still have the `'/* @echo HOST_URL */'` value the preprocess task is able to replace that value with the value required. No black magic, or inverted streams.